# Auto-refresh Chromimum web page in Kiosk mode on Pi3 running Raspbian Jessie

Tags: pi-3, chromium, kiosk

I have Pi3 running Raspbian Jessie that I am setting up as a digital calendar for my family. I used the instructions on this website: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-kiosk/. Everything is working fine, but I want the DAKboard website that Chromimum automatically launches to auto-refresh at a set number of minutes or hours so when a new entry is entered in the calendar, it shows up. I've tried several different ways to do this including the one on that website, but nothing works. This is what I've tried (and I've placed all of these in the /bin/bash ~/kiosk.sh:

```
while true; do
 xdotool keydown ctrl+r; xdotool keyup ctrl+r;
 sleep 900
done
```

Doesn't work. So I tried this code that I found:

```
export=DISPLAY:"0.0"
XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
xdotool getactivewindow
xdotool ctrl+r
sleep 900
```

Doesn't work either. As I said, everything else is working well. I just don't want to use an extension to force the refresh because I want this set up strictly as kiosk with no user input. I've scoured the net for other ideas, and so far everything I've tried has not worked.Any ideas on how to do this? I'm a newer RaspberryPi user, but definitely learning! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using an ancient OS which is no longer supported.

Comment: have you set up `/lib/systemd/system/kiosk.service`, enabled the kiosk service and started it?

Comment: Yes, I set up `/lib/systemd/system/kiosk.service`, enabled it and started it. It runs fine no problem. Everything from the tutorial I linked works perfect. I just can't get the Chromium to auto refresh

Comment: Try with a more resent version of the OS as @Milliways suggested.

Comment: Ok, flashed sd card with Raspbian Bullseye full desktop version. Re-setup everything for the kiosk. Again, everything works fine, but I still can't get Chromium to auto refresh. Tried using the xdotool keyup ctrl+r, and xdotool key ctrl+r and still nothing. It won't refresh.